# Wordpress settings API and serialising data

Tags: php, wordpress

I am using the [WordPress Settings API](http://codex.wordpress.org/Settings_API) to store setting values. If an option form has 10 form elements this means I need to have 10 times `add_settings_field` each with it's own id. This means that for reading the setting value I also need to make 10 `get_option` request, e.g. if I need these setting values in an ajax request.

How would I serialise the data using [WordPress Settings API](http://codex.wordpress.org/Settings_API) and store the values in just one database row and limit the amount of database request to the minimum?

Comment: You can easily keep it as 10 rows but get/set with 1 request.

Comment: How would you do that?

Comment: Hmm - getting it would be cacheable (`wp_get_alloptions`), but setting does seem to require 10 different setting calls (to call the appropriate actions etc.). When first reading your question I understood it as you needing to get/save each option individually through AJAX (and there'd be no reason for this).

Comment: I am developing a plugin that has an option page. The option page is build using the WordPress Settings API, which takes care of saving.

To my understanding the WordPress Setting API does not load values back and assign them to the contact form my it self, one needs to do this within the callback function of add_settings_field e.g. with selected(get_option('vp_autoplay'), 1 ).

The frontside of the plugin needs some of the setting values trough AJAX which I can now easily get with wp_load_alloptions and passing an array with the option names I need.

Comment: Just thinking, I could also use the wp_load_alloptions to get values in the backend also instead of get_option and use the attribute parameter within the add_settings_field function to pass the correct value to each callback function. Note: the callback function renders the html for each form element or option.

Comment: That's a possibility. Personally I'm surprised that WP doesn't have a bulk "get/set" feature that works with KVP arrays.

Comment: I posted a reply with code snippets, one could use it to make his/her own bulk "get" feature. Setting the values are done within WordPress I would guess within the option.php page so no need to make a special function for this at the moment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved my problem using the following code snippet:

```
$required_options = array("option_1", "option_2");
$my_options = array();
$all_options = wp_load_alloptions();
foreach( $all_options as $name => $value ) {
    if (in_array($name, $required_options)) {   
        $my_options[$name] = $value;
    }
}
```

The array `$my_options` I use in the Ajax request to get some of the options I needed as mentions in my question. I am also using it with the WordPress Setting API.

I am creating an option form with 10+ options, using the process described on the [WordPress Setting API](http://codex.wordpress.org/Settings_API) page this means that I need to make 10+ request to the `get_option` function (which makes a request to the database each time). To reduce the amount of request I am using previous mentioned code snippet together with the [add_settings_field](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_settings_field) function.

Example:

```
add_settings_field('myprefix_setting-id', 'This is the setting title', 'myprefix_setting_callback_function', 'general', 'myprefix_settings-section-name', $my_options));
```

Passing the variable `$my_options` as the an additional arguments that are passed to the `$callback` function make the information within `$my_options` available to the code within the `$callback` function (general used to render html form elements).

The only thing you then need to do is to take the additional arguments in your `$callback` function and use it accordingly. E.g.:

```
function myprefix_setting_callback_function($args) {
    echo $args['context'];
}
```

Obvious you can repeat the procedure mentioned above and add the attribute to each `add_settings_field` function call and reduce your database load.